# Get all location within X km radius from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geopandas

I have a set of record in elasticsearch which are inserted into elasticsearch from geoPandas dataframe , Given a pin with lat and long I am trying to search all locations within 2KM of radius of the pin . Below is my Mapping

```
{
   "location_data_info":{
      "mappings":{
         "properties":{
            "geometry":{
               "properties":{
                  "coordinates":{
                     "type":"float"
                  },
                  "type":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "id":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            },
            "properties":{
               "properties":{
                  "Address":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "Lat":{
                     "type":"float"
                  },
                  "Long":{
                     "type":"float"
                  },
                  "AreaId":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "keyword":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "type":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "keyword":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Below is one sample record from elasticsearch

```
{
   "_index":"location_data_info",
   "_type":"_doc",
   "_id":"RnwP2IkBY01f93x2B-J-",
   "_version":1,
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "id":"8",
      "type":"Feature",
      "properties":{
         "AreaId":"123456",
         "Address":"Golden Gate Bridge",
         "Lat":37.821343,
         "Long":-122.479731
      },
      "geometry":{
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[
            37.821343,
            -122.479731
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I used the below query to get records which are within 2km of a given pin location but it outputs all records and no filter seems to have been applied . I am not sure if there is any wrong .Query which I used is

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "2km",
                    "geometry.coordinates" : {
                        "lat" : 37.760712
                        "lon" : -122.393113
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I change my mapping to below the result is same , I get all records instead of getting records within 2 KM distance

```
{
  "location_data_info": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "geometry": {
          "properties": {
            "coordinates": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "type": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "properties": {
          "properties": {
            "Address": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "Lat": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "Long": {
              "type": "float"
            },
            "AreaId": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the below code to insert data into elasticsearch

```
final_file_data = DataFrame which has all area info including lat and long 

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            final_file_data,
            geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
                final_file_data["Long"],
                final_file_data["Lat"],
            ),
            crs={"init": "EPSG:4326"},
        )

data_json_file = gdf.to_json()
        data_to_send=json.loads(data_json_file)
        es_data_to_send = data_to_send['features']


        self.es.insert_bulk_record('location_data_info', json.dumps(es_data_to_send), file_name,False)
```

Has anyone faced similar issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `geometry` field is not mapped correctly, it should be mapped as a [`geo_shape`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#geo-point-type) like this:

```
  "geometry": {
    "type": "geo_shape"
  }
```

You need to recreate your index with the right mapping and then the following query will work:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "2km",
                    "geometry" : {                <---- change this field name
                        "lat" : 37.760712
                        "lon" : -122.393113
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question with the code I am using to insert data into elasticsearch .I am currently using geoDataFrame which would have lat and long to insert data into ES . Am I using the wrong conversion in geoDataFrame ?

Comment: You need to properly [create your index mapping](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.9.0/api.html#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create) before indexing your data

Comment: I followed the exact same tutorial https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-query.html for "type": "geo_point" with same data and used the same query it still doesnt filter and sends all records

Comment: You need `geo_shape` not `geo_point`

Comment: I tried with geo_shapes too  ,my mapping https://jsonblob.com/1139843401184567296 and one sample data https://jsonblob.com/1139843572257644544 . Not sure if I am entering the lat long correctly as it inserts data correctly .

Comment: I was finally able to get it using geo_point ..instead of get I did post and it worked . https://discuss.elastic.co/t/geo-distance-not-working/55151 Helped it